# Is there a smarter way to evaluate the current date against the 26 week calendar than a long case statement?

Tags: vba, ms-access, switch-statement

I have a very long Case statement that is evaluating the current date to determine if it is within that week.  Like this

```
 Dim today As Date 

 Select Case today    
   Case today >= "9/1/2015" And today <= "9/7/2015"
     shipdateweeknum = 1048
   Case today >= "9/8/2015" And today <= "9/14/2015"
     shipdateweeknum = 1049 
   Case today >= "9/15/2015" And today <= "9/21/2015"
     shipdateweeknum = 1050
   .
   .
   . 
   Case Else
     shipdateweeknum = 1083 ' 1083 is last week of 2015.
 End Select
```

I am using shipdateweeknum later in the function in some SQL.

It just seems there could be a function that I am not thinking about, or just a simpler, simpler = less code to update each year when the calendar moves.

Thank you

Comment: You could use datediff, asking for week numbers. `shipdateweeknum = = DateDiff("ww", "7/01/2000", Date)`

Comment: 1099 - 792 = 307 ... so more than 300 weeks from 9/1/2015 through the last week of 2015?

Comment: First `Case` has the period of 7 days (1..7), but second and third have 8 days (8..15, 16..23) each. Am I missing something?

Comment: Ugh.  My concentration is shot today but I can tell you "ww" is week and "q" is quarter.  Since your year runs 3rd quarter, 4th quarter, 1st quarter, 2nd quarter, you'll have to create a function that determines the last date of the 2nd quarter and do a datediff in weeks from that date to your current date.  Too much Maths for my head today.  :o(

Comment: since you edited the code this change will give you the weeks.  `shipdateweeknum = DateDiff("ww", "8/01/1995", Date)`

Answer (score 0):

I would parse the day and month, then use this to compute the day number in the year (like: 26/1/2015 =>26).

Then after you can simply deduce the week number for the current year and using a reference (like first week of 2015 is 1048) you can deduce your result.

The good thing is that by taking the reference as the origin of dates for your language, and by taking special years into account, you will get a function that will work for any date.

Answer (score 0):

This expression will return your weeknumber:

```
WeekNumber = DateDiff("ww", #1995/8/1#, Date, vbTuesday)
```

or (in a query):

```
WeekNumber: DateDiff("ww",#1995/8/1#,Date(),3)
```